# How to make an auto clicker in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a clicker game and I wanted to know how to make a button that when I click on it, a number slowly goes up with intervals. I don't really know how to do the intervals and I've tried doing loops but loops are instant and have no intervals.

```js
var number = 0;

function increase() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">
    by 1
  </button>
<div>
  number:
  <div id="number">
    0
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone turn this into an auto clicker? as said above, i just want to click on the button once and have the value of the variable "number" go up. Thanks.

Comment: setTimeout, setInterval.....

Comment: Why defer on the script?

Comment: sorry i thought i can make more than 1 answers

Comment: No, alas not. And with more rep you can vote others up

Comment: i hope thats soon because i hate not being able to show my opinion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is mine showing how to

- use an interval
- use eventListener (unobtrusive coding)
- clear the interval
- how to increment a number and change speed
- how to use data attributes
- how to use classes and querySelector

```js
var number = 0,
  increment = 1,
  speed=1000, // one second
  tId;

function inc() {
  clearInterval(tId); // stop anything already running
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += increment;
  }, speed);
}
function changeSpeed() {
  speed = +this.getAttribute("data-speed"); // get attribute and convert to number
  inc();
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  document.querySelectorAll(".start").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", function() {
       increment = +this.getAttribute("data-inc") ; // get from button and convert to number 
       inc()
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() { // when clicking
    clearInterval(tId);
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".speed").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", changeSpeed);
  });

});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="1">By 1</button>
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="10">By 10</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="1000">One a sec</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="500">Two a sec</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
<div>
  number: <span id="number">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer is very complex and i will use it in the future. good job (:

Comment: Complete, not complex :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an interval with setInterval();

```
var number = 0;

function increase() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1
    }
}

setInterval(increase, 1000);
```

This should increase the number every second.

If you want to stop it then you can say:

```
var interval = setInterval(increase, 1000);

clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: i cant accept the answer now but it worked. SOOOOO simple! thanks!

Comment: ive figured out that it cant get any faster than 1. is there a way to change that?

Comment: @ThomasTallman You mean 1 second or 1 millisecond? If you want it faster than 1 second then reduce the second argument (1000 === 1000 milliseconds === 1 second) 

If you want it faster than 1ms you'll just have to increase the amount your increment value

Comment: Or even try using two intervals instead?

Comment: ok. so 1000 is milliseconds, which is 1 second. i did 1 milisecond, and i was wondering if there is anything faster than that. EDIT: true. i should just increase the increment

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 0;
function increase () {
    number++;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number;
}
```

Try this out.
I believe the issue is, you're not actually incrementing the variable 'number'. What you're instead doing is setting the content of the element number to number +=1;

So since number is 0;
it will only ever show 1 on the HTML.

If you want the number to increment by one automatically after you've clicked the button once. Create a setInterval.

```
setInterval(() => {
    increase()
}, 5000) // increase every 5 seconds
```

Comment: that's a simpler way of what i did but not an auto clicker. but helpful because its neater.

Comment: If you want to make it automatic, do a setInterval.
Check out my edit :)

Comment: `setInterval(increase, 5000)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function increase() {
    setInterval(() => document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1, 1000)
}
```

setInterval() will call an anonymous function which increment the number each second (1000 ms) until you call clearInterval()

Answer (score 1):

```js
var number = 0;

function increase() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">
    by 1
  </button>
<div>
  number:
  <div id="number">
    0
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var number = 0,
  increment = 1,
  speed=1000, // one second
  tId;

function inc() {
  clearInterval(tId); // stop anything already running
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += increment;
  }, speed);
}
function changeSpeed() {
  speed = +this.getAttribute("data-speed"); // get attribute and convert to number
  inc();
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  document.querySelectorAll(".start").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", function() {
       increment = +this.getAttribute("data-inc") ; // get from button and convert to number 
       inc()
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() { // when clicking
    clearInterval(tId);
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".speed").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", changeSpeed);
  });

});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="1">By 1</button>
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="10">By 10</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="1000">One a sec</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="500">Two a sec</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
<div>
  number: <span id="number">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Here's a snippet:

```js
var number = 0,
  increment = 1,
  speed = 1000, // one second
  tId;

function inc() {
  clearInterval(tId); // stop anything already running
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += increment;
  }, speed);
}

function changeSpeed() {
  speed = +this.getAttribute("data-speed"); // get attribute and convert to number
  inc();
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  document.querySelectorAll(".start").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", function() {
      increment = +this.getAttribute("data-inc"); // get from button and convert to number 
      inc()
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() { // when clicking
    clearInterval(tId);
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".speed").forEach(function(but) {
    but.addEventListener("click", changeSpeed);
  });

});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="1">By 1</button>
<button type="button" class="start" data-inc="10">By 10</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="1000">One a sec</button>
<button type="button" class="speed" data-speed="3000">Two a sec</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
<div>
  number: <span id="number">0</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `setInterval(function(){ /* do something every 3 seconds */ }, 3000);`

You can call the function in the interval parameter or write the code inside.

You can look at [these](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) examples.