# Autoclick javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an autoclick event , that clicks in a link after 10/30 seconds. I have done this code but its not working. maybe it's simple but I don't know so many javascript. Thanks guys!

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<a href="https://dkuero.com" class="dkuero">dkuero</a>

<script>
setTimeout(envio() {
$('.dkuero').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` only fires once, you probably want to use `setInterval()`

Comment: `1000` is one second.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284406/how-to-make-an-auto-clicker-in-javascript/55284542#55284542

Comment: You also didn't include jQuery.

Comment: Instead of setTimeout(envio() {...should be setTimeout(function() {

Comment: Whatever you're trying to build here, you should rethink it. This "click" will amlost certain trigger the popup blocker in pretty much every modern browser.

Comment: it's a redirection to another website, so when they enter that url after 10 secons for example it will simulate a click to another website.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with `setInterval` because the delay changes every time. Instead, use a recurring [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

```html
<a href="https://dkuero.com" id="demo">dkuero</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar = setTimeout(myTimer, random(5000, 10000));

  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").click();
    setTimeout(myTimer, random(5000, 10000));
  }

  function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
</script>
```